# Extract each URL with a unique combination of parameters

Tags: bash

I have a list of URLs:

```
https://example.com/invite?id=12
https://example.com/invite?id=12&per=5675
https://example.com/invite?id=156&per=2290
https://example.com/invite?id=12309&per=37245
https://example.com/sudo?root=false&admin=true
https://example.com/invite?id=453&admin=false
https://example.com/invite?id=278&admin=true
https://example.com/invite?id=90&admin=false
```

And I want to extract those with a unique combination of parameters. So the expected output is:

```
https://example.com/invite?id=12
https://example.com/invite?id=12&per=5675
https://example.com/invite?id=90&admin=false
https://example.com/sudo?root=false&admin=true
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk '!seen[gensub(/=[^&]*/,"","g")]++' file
```

Comment: But it also should filter out the common urls like.

https:/example.com/id/cycling/rank/124103?limit=109
https:/example.com/id/cycling/rank/124133?limit=112
https:/example.com/id/cycling/rank/124101?limit=166

And print only one url among the similar one from.
https:/example.com/id/cycling/rank/124101?limit=166